# Showing Flutter documentation on mouse hover in VS Code not working

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Unlike Android Studio, I’ve not been able to get VS Code to show a Widget’s documentation when I hover over it with the mouse. I have installed the Flutter/Dart extension and have set dart.previewLsp to true. Is there a way to do this in VS Code? I'm on Mac OS 10.15.7 (Catalina) with VS Code 1.54.3.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it shows when I hover over the TabController Widget:

[image]

When you CTRL+CLICK on the widget itself in VSCode it gives you the entire documentation:

[image]

Comment: Yes, if I option-click I get the full documentation (I'm on Mac/Catalina), but hovering gives me nothing.

Comment: sorry for asking, can you tell me what vscode theme is this